# SD card reader doesn't work on 16.10 on Asus Zenbook UX305FA

Tags: asus, 16.10, sd-card, card-reader

I cannot find anyone with the same laptop and distro with this issue. Please help!

`lspci -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI [8086:1604] (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5300 [8086:161e] (rev 08)
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller [8086:160c] (rev 08)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1603] (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller [8086:9cb1] (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 [8086:9cba] (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:9ca0] (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:9c90] (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 [8086:9c96] (rev e3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9cc7] (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] [8086:9c83] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9ca2] (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller [8086:9ca4] (rev 03)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 064e:9700 Suyin Corp. Asus Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c025 Logitech, Inc. MX500 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a relative new computer and if you are using Ubuntu 16.04 you dont have the kernel updates that will fix it.

Installing 4.6.2 could possibly fix it. Download the files by running the below commands.

```
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6.2-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.2-040602_4.6.2-040602.201606100516_all.deb

wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6.2-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.2-040602-generic_4.6.2-040602.201606100516_amd64.deb

wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6.2-yakkety/linux-image-4.6.2-040602-generic_4.6.2-040602.201606100516_amd64.deb
```

Install the kernel

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.6.2*.deb linux-image-4.6.2*.deb
```

Finally run sudo restart to reboot. If something goes wrong, you can reboot back to the current kernel you are using by holding SHIFT down when booting Ubuntu. This opens up Grub and allows you to select your current kernel version.

If 4.6.2 does not fix your issue a later kernel version possibly could. With later models, despite running latest Ubuntu patches, not all hardware is supported.